# how to put the sql query upgrade to drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

i am new to drupal 7.

```
$sql = "SELECT nid, title FROM {node} n
    WHERE nid $sql_op %d
    AND type IN (" . implode(',', $quoted_types) . ")
    AND status = 1
    ORDER BY nid $order
    LIMIT 1";
  $result = db_query($sql, $current_node->nid, $type);
  $data = db_fetch_object($result);
```

how to put the  above sql query upgrade to drupal 7  thank you.

Comment: Where did you get this from? It must of shown you a location to place this?

Comment: http://2bits.com/articles/simple-previous-next-navigation-node-title.html i want to use it in drupal 7, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like this for D7:

```
$result = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->condition('n.nid', $current_node->nid, $sql_op)
  ->condition('type', $type)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->orderBy('nid', $order)
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->execute();

$data = $result->fetchObject();
```

Untested, of course, so report back if this works. Also make sure that you use the correct types, not sure why the D6 version uses an IN statement for the type but then only has a single $type. Note that in the above code, you can either pass a single value or an array of values to condition(), both works.

Comment: i am sorry, it can't work.there are two conditions. is it an error?

Comment: There are three, just like your in your query. No, that's not an error. What exactly doesn't work? Is there an error? Always provide detailed information when something doesn't work...

Comment: my IDE show an error on this line ->condition('n.nid', $current_node->nid, $sql_op)  but i don't know why?

Comment: Well, make sure that those two arguments exist. Also, try to run it, your IDE might be wrong and running it will give you a better error description.

Comment: Ah, there was a missing parenthesis, fixed it above.

Comment: i am sorry.it shows "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in template.php......

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->condition('n.nid', $current_node->nid, $sql_op)
  ->condition('type', $quoted_types, 'IN')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->orderBy('nid', $order)
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->execute();

$data = $result->fetchObject();
```